# Disable option never goes away for network adapters

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I'm running Windows 7.

Whenever I disable the wireless adapter, the "Disable" option does not change to "enable".

Similarly, for the "Local Area Connection", when I click on "Disable", the adapter gets disabled, but the "Disable" option remains.

In summary, I am never offered the option to enable an adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I was able to Disable and Enable my Local Area Connection.
2) However, the behaviour of the red X was strange, even counter-intuitive.
3) Humbly suggest that you give it one more go.  Try a ping or two to double-check?

Comment: So, I did test whether I was actually connected the internet by pinging a couple of websites. When I disable the first time, I am actually disconnected from the internet.

Thanks, though!